# Toggle Fullscreen exit

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, fullscreen

I have the following javascript that is triggered by a button in my HTML:

```
function toggleFullScreen(){

    if(v.requestFullScreen){
        v.requestFullScreen();
    }
    else if(v.webkitRequestFullScreen){
        v.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
    else if(v.mozRequestFullScreen){
        v.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
}
```

How can I extend this JS code to incorporate the ability to **exit fullscreen**? What are the best practices for this?

Comment: Use [screenfull.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js), have a look at the [demo](https://sindresorhus.com/screenfull.js).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is actually a fully functional example on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode#Toggling_fullscreen_mode

Quote:

> **Toggling fullscreen mode**
>
> This code is called when the user hits the Enter key, as seen above.
>
> ```
> function toggleFullScreen() {
>   if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
>       !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  // current working methods
>     if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
>       document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();
>     } else if (document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
>       document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();
>     } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
>       document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
>     } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
>       document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
>     }
>   } else {
>     if (document.exitFullscreen) {
>       document.exitFullscreen();
>     } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
>       document.msExitFullscreen();
>     } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
>       document.mozCancelFullScreen();
>     } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
>       document.webkitExitFullscreen();
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> This starts by looking at the value of the fullscreenElement attribute
>   on the document (checking it prefixed with both moz, ms, and webkit).
>   If it's null, the document is currently in windowed mode, so we need
>   to switch to fullscreen mode. Switching to fullscreen mode is done by
>   calling either element.mozRequestFullScreen() msRequestFullscreen()or
>   webkitRequestFullscreen(), depending on which is available.
>
> If fullscreen mode is already active (fullscreenElement is non-null),
>   we call document.mozCancelFullScreen(), msExitFullscreen or
>   webkitExitFullscreen(), again depending on which browser is in use.

Comment: just about to post this code, brilliant resource, thanks for being so prompt! will accept in 2 mins, reputation++ :)

Comment: This will only work if the fullscreen was requested for some element. If the fullscreen is initiated by the browser itself (e.g. when the user presses F11), this will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Have you try something from this ?

```
exitFullscreen();
mozCancelFullScreen();
webkitExitFullscreen();
msExitFullscreen();
```

Look there :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

or:

http://blog.pearce.org.nz/2011/11/firefoxs-html-full-screen-api-enabled.html

Is this enough helpful for you ?

Comment: How can I adapat these functions to my code?  I've been trying for the last hour :)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I've retrieved the functions needed!

Comment: No problem :) Can you mark my answer with thick ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Chris Code is from website what I sent you :D This was theft :D

Answer (score 1):

1. Get jQuery from: http://jquery.com/download/
2. Get screenfull.min.js from:
       [https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/%E2%80%8E)
3. ‎Include them in `<head>...</head>`
4. Assign an id to `<body>` ex. mainBody
5. Place the function before the closing body tag ie. `</body>`

   ```
   <script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
   <script src="js/screenfull.min.js"></script> 
   </head>

   <body id="mainBody">
   <!--[whatever]-->
   <script>
                $(function tScreen()
                {
                 if(!screenfull.enabled) 
                 { return false; }
                 screenfull.request(document.getElementById('mainBody'));
                });

                $('#toggle').click(function () 
                { screenfull.toggle($('#mainBody')[0]);});
          </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```